# Can MongoDB use an index when checking for existence of a field with $exists operator?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

If I have data in my `users` collection that looks like:

```
{ name: '...', 
  email: '...', 
  ...,
  photos: {
     123: { url: '...', title: '...', ... },
     456: { url: '...', title: '...', ... },
     ...
  }
}
```

And I want to find which user owns photo id 127, then I am using the query:

```
db.users.find( {'photos.127': {'$exists' => true} } );
```

I've tried, but it doesn't seem possible to get MongoDB to use an index for this query. The index I tried was: `db.users.ensureIndex({photos:1});`.  And when I used `explain()` mongo told me it was using a BasicCursor (i.e., no index was used).

Is it possible to create an index that mongo will use for this query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Updated:

Seems `$exists` queries use index properly now based on these tickets
[$exists queries should use index](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-393) &  [{$exists: false} will not use index](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-393)

Old Answer:

No, there is no way to tell mongodb to use index for exists query. **Indexing is completely related to data**. Since **$exists is only related to the keys (fields)** it cant be used in indexes.

$exists just verifies whether the given key (or field) exists in the document.

Comment: NO!!! I tested with mongodb 2.4.3, and it USES the index. Note that nonexistent fields, have value Null in index.

Comment: MongoDB 3.0.3: `explain` for both `find({field: {$exists: 1}})` and `find({field: {$ne: null}})` looks like it's going to use index, but whereas the second query finishes instantly, the first one stucks (w/ full scan, I guess).

Comment: Well that sucks. Keys are data and should be able to be indexed. Allowing objects as data kinda sucks if you can't index them..

Comment: `$exists` uses index now (tested on mongo 3.2)

Comment: Will it be used in agregation too? I have issues with a pipeline like so: `"$match": {         "foo": "someValue", "bar": { "$exists": true } } ` it seems to respect the index on "foo" but not on "bar". I've a compound index on foo and bar + an index on bar.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12869 is still open.  This has not been properly resolved, since it will only use the index in certain cases and/or give you incorrect results.

Answer (score 8):

As of June 2022 the index **CANNOT** be used for `${exists: true}` case and **CAN BE ONLY PARTIALLY** used for the half of other cases. There is a major (IMO) design bug with the MongoDB index which people are still often unaware of so I'm posting this answer with a workaround for some cases.

The issue is that MongoDB indexes non-existing fields as `null`s and as such these fields are indistinguishable from `null`s from the index perspective. In addition there is some mess related to JS analogy, where `undefined === null` is false but `undefined == null` is true.
That means:

- When searching for `{$exists: false}` the index **can be used**. For that the index is scanned for `null` retrieving references to documents with both null and non-existing values, documents are fetched, and documents with values equal to null are filtered out. Corresponding MongoDB stages: `[null, null] IXSCAN` and `FETCH with {"$not" : {$exists: true}} filter`.
- When searching for `{field: null}`  the index **can be used**. For that, just the index scan is needed. MongoDB parses that as `{field: { $eq: null }}`. For some likely historical reasons Mongo also searches for deprecated `undefined` type/value: `[undefined, undefined]U[null, null] IXSCAN`. IMO it would be way more logical to just interpret equality as value equality and not include non-existing fields in the results. But it is what it is.
- To REALLY search for value equal to null, we need to search for `field: {$type: "null"}`. Index **can be used**. Similarly to the first case, stages are: `[null, null] IXSCAN` and `FETCH with {'$type': [10]} filter`. Documents with non-existing field are unnecessarily fetched and then filtered out.
- If you need to retrieve all existing values, i.e. including those with value `null`, then you are in a bad luck. The search query is `{field: {$exists: true}}`. **Index cannot be used**. If mongo was using the index, it would include values indexed as `null` to include documents with the field equal to null, to later filter out non-existing values. So full index would be needed, and so the full collection scan is more efficient. Mongo stages: `COLLSCAN with { '$exists': true } filter`.
- If you can live without values equal to `null`, i.e. it is fine to not include `$type: null` in results, then **index can be used**. If you know your field type is e.g. ObjectId then you can search for `{field: {$type: "object"}}`, for the list of types: `{field: {$type: ["number", "object"]}}`, or just `{field: {$ne: "null"}}`. The latter will exclude `null` and `undefined` types from the search. Mongo stages are:

  - `[{},[]) IXSCAN` and `FETCH`
  - `'[nan.0, inf.0]U[{}, [])'` and `FETCH`
  - `[MinKey, undefined)U(null, MaxKey] IXSCAN` and `FETCH`.

There is an issue filed on Feb 2014: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12869. Unfortunately, MongoDB hasn't prioritized it yet, nor reflected the issue in the official documentation.

Answer (score 7):

$exist will not use index, but you can change your data structure to

```
photos: [
     {id:123, url: '...', title: '...', ... },
     {id:456, url: '...', title: '...', ... },
     ...
  ]
```

and then use

```
db.users.ensureIndex({photos.id:1})
```

to create index for photo id.

It seems I am wrong, in fact, you can force your $exists query to use your index.
Let us go on using the above structure, but your photo id is not certainly contained , that is to say
some docs will have the key 'id' and some will not. Then you can create sparse index on it:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({'photos.id': 1}, {'sparse': true})
```

then query like this:

```
db.users.find({'photos.id': {$exists: true}}).hint({'photos.id': 1})
```

you can add explain to see if the query is using index.
Here is my result, my collection's mobile key is similar to your photos.id:

```
> db.test.count()
50000
> db.test.find({'mobile': {$exists: true}}).hint({'mobile': 1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor mobile_1",
        "nscanned" : 49999,
        "nscannedObjects" : 49999,
        "n" : 49999,
        "millis" : 138,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "mobile" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        }
}

> db.test.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.test",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "mobile" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.test",
                "name" : "mobile_1",
                "sparse" : true,
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

Hope to help!

Comment: `$exists` uses index now (tested on mongo 3.2)

Answer (score 6):

[Since MongoDB 2.0](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-393) `$exists` queries should use an index. Unfortunately this fix has [disappeared in the newest version and will be fixed in MongoDB 2.5](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10608)

Answer (score 3):

Posting it here with latest changes as of February 2023 -
if you wish to use $exists with an index, better consult the table here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

If you wish to use an index on a query of { $exists: true }, best approach would be to use sparse index