# Check that Field Exists with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

So I'm attempting to find all records who have a field set and isn't null.

I try using `$exists`, however according to the [MongoDB documentation,](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) this query will return fields who equal null.

> `$exists` does match documents that contain the field that stores the null value.

So I'm now assuming I'll have to do something like this:

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck" : { $exists : true, $not : null } })
```

Whenever I try this however, I get the error `[invalid use of $not]`  Anyone have an idea of how to query for this?

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Use `$ne` (for "not equal")

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck": { $ne: null } })
```

Comment: What does this return? A null collection? A single item? An array?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns: what `find` always returns: a collection of records, matching the criteria.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev AFAIK it returns a cursor

Comment: @fernandohur: yeah, but if you have less than one page of documents, you won't even see the difference. And if you were to run this query from external driver, I'm pretty sure most of them shield you from the cursor implementation detail.

Comment: I know this is old, but as this is the accepted answer: `{$exists: true}` is redundant, just `{$ne: null}` is enough.

Comment: @SergeiKuzmin: thanks for pointing this out. It is enough now, but (I'm pretty sure) this wasn't the case back then.

Answer (score 46):

Suppose we have a collection like below:

```
{ 
  "_id":"1234"
  "open":"Yes"
  "things":{
             "paper":1234
             "bottle":"Available"
             "bottle_count":40
            } 
}
```

We want to know if the bottle field is present or not?

Ans:

```
db.products.find({"things.bottle":{"$exists":true}})
```

Comment: `When <boolean> is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null.` [From the docs.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Comment: yep, but i don' see why a DB would contain the value null, it's sloppy

Answer (score 6):

i find that this works for me

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').findOne({"fieldName" : {$ne: null}})
```

Answer (score 4):

This comment is written in **2021** and applies **for MongoDB 5.X  and earlier versions.**

If you value **query performance** **never use $exists** (or use it only when you have a sparse index over the field that is queried. the sparse index should match the criteria of the query, meaning, if searching for  **$exists:true**, the sparse index should be over **field:{$exist:true}** , if you are querying where **$exists:true** the sparse index should be over **field:{$exist:false}**

Instead use :

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck": {  $ne: null } })
```

or

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck": {  $eq: null } })
```

this will require that you include the fieldToCheck   in every document of the collection, however - the performance will be vastly improved.

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72843232/1301837. It explains the current limitations of `$exists` with full index and the reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.<COLLECTION NAME>.find({ "<FIELD NAME>": { $exists: true, $ne: null } })
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i added new field `isDeleted : true` to only fields that are deleted.

So for all other records there was no `isDeleted` field, so i wanted to get all the fields that `isDeleted` either does not exist or false. So query is

```
.find({ isDeleted: { $ne: true } });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I Tried to convert it into boolean condition , where if document with
> table name already exist , then it will append in the same document ,
> otherwise it will create one .

table_name is the variable using which i am trying to find the document

```
query = { table_name : {"$exists": "True"}}
    
    result = collection.find(query)
    flag = 0
    for doc in result:
        collection.update_one({}, { "$push" : { table_name : {'name':'hello'} } } )
        flag = 1
    if (flag == 0):
        collection.insert_one({ table_name : {'roll no' : '20'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

aggregate example

https://mongoplayground.net/p/edbKil4Zvwc

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "finishedAt": {
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "tags.name": "Singapore"
        },
        {
          "tags.name": "ABC"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```