# How to query all items in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDb called items
items contain two types of item
1) pizza
2) drinks

how I query just the pizza if my mongoose schema was like this:

```
let items = new Schema({
    pizza: {
        name: String,
        price: [Number],
        subType: [String]
    },

    drinks : {
        name: String,
        price: Number,

    }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check that Field Exists with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868016/check-that-field-exists-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second argument of `find` operation to select only a subset of fields you want in the output. You can read about `find` at this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)

The query as given below should be what you should be interested in.

```
db.coll.find({}, {pizza: 1})
```