# How to check if field exists for a specified id in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I m using NodeJs and MongoDB as a backend service for my app.I want to check if field exist in database for a specified id.I have database structure like below:

```
{
   {
      _id:"1"
       Name:"Digi"
   }, 
   {
      _id:"2"
       Name:"Digi"
       Place:"London"
   } 
 }
```

I am using MongoDB driver for NodeJS.

Someone please let me know how to achieve this.

**THANKS**

Comment: `db.collection.find({ "Place": { "$exists": true } })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check that Field Exists with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868016/check-that-field-exists-with-mongodb)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet i want to check this for some particular id lets say for id :"1" is there place field exists.

Comment: You can still extend the given query: `db.collection.find({ "_id": "1", "Place": { "$exists": true } })`

Comment: @mbuechmann how can i use callback with this query in order to perform some task based on result.

Comment: Thanks all for help finally got it.