# How to write a function to fetch the data with same key but different value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i want to read the document from mongo DB which is having same key but different value.

suppose there are documents having `scenario` field   but different value

ex - document 1 having  scenario : 'something1', document2 having scenario : 'something2'...

Sample O/P

```
 {{_id=6114ce6514796e5fbe316be2, App=PRO_WH_DS, Other Voucher Code=, Date and Time Performed=, SnApp Error=, Done=, Unit Tax Quoted=$25.16, AQ perDayNetPrice=, Test #=WH POS 2.A, Scenario=WH POS 2.A}} 

{{_id=6114ce6514796e5fbe316bde, App=PRO_WH_DS, Other Voucher Code=, Date and Time Performed=, SnApp Error=, Done=, Unit Tax Quoted=$26.51, AQ perDayNetPrice=, Gold "Upgrade Tax"=, Gold Source=, , Scenario=WH HERA}}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to find all of the documents that contain a certain field?

Comment: yes , like i want to filter all the documents that have scenario  field (which is common in all document but diffrent value ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check that Field Exists with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868016/check-that-field-exists-with-mongodb)

Comment: _id
:
6114ce6514796e5fbe316bda
App
:
:
""
:
""
SnApp Ticket Value
:
""
SnApp Ticket Tax
:
""
AQ netPrice
:
""
Status
:
"Complete"
Execution Environment
:
"STAGE"
Order ID
:
"VGVXVKRD"
Gold "Net Price to Seller"
:
""
Test #
:
"WH HERA 1.F"
Scenario
:
"WH HERA 1.F"}

_id
:
6114ce6614796e5fbe316be4
App
:
SnApp Ticket Value
:
""
SnApp Ticket Tax
:
""
AQ netPrice
:
""
Status
:
"Complete"
Execution Environment
:
"STAGE"
Order ID
:
"KJWT62312828"
Gold "Net Price to Seller"
:
""
Test #
:
"WH HERA 2.A"
Scenario
:
"WH HERA 2.A"}

Comment: How to fetch where scenarion is common but diffrent value

Comment: What do you consider to be common?

Comment: if you see the data i have given there  'Scenario ' field is common in each documents  but diffrent value , so i want to write a querry inside a function which can give the document as per my Scenario value input . And

Comment: I can see they start with similar letters. Is that what you want, to find all documents with a scenario that starts with `WH HERA`?

Comment: scenario value will be hard coded ., i.e if i am passing 3 scenario value then i should get the document as per my I/p . like if i am passing scenario = 'A',''B ' then the document having scenario value 'A' and 'B ' should display in console

Comment: Are you trying to do exact matches? For example, match all documents that have a scenario equal to "scenario1" OR "scenario2". Or are you trying to match documents that have a scenario that starts with a given input?

Comment: match all documents that have a scenario equal to "scenario1" AND "scenario2"

Comment: Do you mean something like [this?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the--in-operator-to-match-values)

Comment: Data fetch::Document{{_id=6114ce6514796e5fbe316be2, App=PRO_WH_DS, Other Voucher Code=, Date and Time Performed=, SnApp Error=, Done=, Unit Tax Quoted=$25.16, AQ perDayNetPrice=,  Test #=WH POS 2.A, Scenario=WH POS 2.A

Data fetch::Document{{_id=6114ce6514796e5fbe316bde, App=PRO_WH_DS, Other Voucher Code=, Date and Time Performed=, SnApp Error=, Done=, Unit Tax Quoted=$26.51, AQ perDayNetPrice=, Gold "Upgrade Tax"=, Gold Source=, , Scenario=WH HERA

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample documents, how you want to query the sample documents, and which documents should be returned.

Comment: Sample O/P 

{{_id=6114ce6514796e5fbe316be2, App=PRO_WH_DS, Other Voucher Code=, Date and Time Performed=, SnApp Error=, Done=, Unit Tax Quoted=$25.16, AQ perDayNetPrice=,  Test #=WH POS 2.A, Scenario=WH POS 2.A}}

{{_id=6114ce6514796e5fbe316bde, App=PRO_WH_DS, Other Voucher Code=, Date and Time Performed=, SnApp Error=, Done=, Unit Tax Quoted=$26.51, AQ perDayNetPrice=, Gold "Upgrade Tax"=, Gold Source=, , Scenario=WH HERA}}

Comment: Where Scenario=WH POS 2.A, Scenario=WH HERA  and the values (WH POS 2.A, WH HERA ) will pass from a function and it should get display in the console

Comment: Please include information like this in the question, *not* the comments. It looks like you want something like the $in operator I linked to. Did you look at it?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts as per the link written quarry 



async function findListingScenarion (client, {

  nameoflist1 =' ',
  nameoflist2 = ''

}  ) {
  const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find ({
    Scenario: {
      $eq: nameoflist1,
      nameoflist2
    }
  });

Comment: and calling that inside a main()

await findListingScenarion (client, nameoflist1 = 'WH HERA 2.A', nameoflist1 ='WH HERA 2.B')

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in the comments, it sounds like you want to match documents where the value of `Scenario` is equal to one of two values. `{ Scenario: { $eq: nameoflist1, nameoflist2 } }` won't work because it isn't a valid filter. This is when you'd want to use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in) operator.

[The section I linked in the comments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the--in-operator-to-match-values) shows a scenario just like yours. Following along, we would reach a query like this:

```
db.price_check_validation.find( { Scenario: { $in: ['WH HERA 2.A', 'WH HERA 2.B'] } } )
```

Comment: yes , correct as per the suggstion wtitten the querry as below 

async function finddata (client, l1, l2)
{
  const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find ({
    Scenario: {
      $in: [
        'l1',
        'l2'
      ]
    }
  });
}


And the value i am passing fro the another function 

await finddata (client, 'WH HERA 2.A', 'WH HERA 1.F') ;

not sure getting error , is my approach is correct ?

Comment: Your approach is not correct because you want the values of the variables named `l1` and `l2` but you are passing two strings with the values  `"l1"` and `"l2"`. You need to remove the quotes around `l1` and `l2` in the filter document.

Comment: async function finddata (client, l1, l2)
{
  const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find ({
    Scenario: {
      $in: [
        l1,
        l2
      ]
    }
  });
}




but it displaying error -

{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

Comment: That appears to be a separate issue related to the NPM package mongoose. Searching that error brings up other stack overflow questions. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson) might help you.

Comment: yah , i have change the path to 

 bson = require('../browser_build/bson'); but its not showing any O/p