# How would I find documents based on whether a field exists AND another that doesn't, in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a bunch of documents that consists of fields "Data" and "Text". Some docs have either one, while some have neither of these. How would I query through pyMongo to get documents that HAVE the field "Data" and DO NOT HAVE the field "Text"?

I've tried the below queries but mongo doesn't return any files.

**METHOD 1:**

```
files = collection.find({"Data": {"$exists": "true"}, {"Text": {"$exists": "false"}})

for file in files:
    print(file)
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
files = collection.find({"$and": [{"Data": {"$exists": "true"}}, {"Text": {"$exists": "false"}}]})

for file in files:
    print(file)
```

> NOTE: I'm currently trying the query on a database where no collections have the "Text" field (yet), but the query should still work w.r.t the logic. It being:
>
> Return docs with "Data" AND not having "Text"

Comment: Try [`"$exists": true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) instead of `"$exists": "true"`

Comment: hey, i'm using pyMongo which is a native python driver for MongoDB and it accepts commands only in string. The command **files = collection.find({"Data": {"$exists": "true"})** works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/

Try this

```
  collection.find({"Data": {"$exists": "true"}, {"Text": null })
```

query matches documents that either contain the Text field whose value is null or 
     that do not contain the Text field.

If you could not resolve this then please post your data store in collections for 
     reference and your schema structure.this will help us if you have problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using *None* instead of False as Anushka pointed out and it worked.

```
files = coll.find({"Data": {"$exists": "true"}, "Text": None})
```

If anyone knows why my initial attempt as stated below did not work, please comment on this answer. Thanks.

```
files = collection.find({"Data": {"$exists": "true"}, {"Text": {"$exists": "false"}})
```

Comment: Ah, just noticed, that attempt didn't work about you wrapped the `Text` part into a hash/object of its own (and you're missing a closing curly brace somewhere there)

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that there. But I substituting None/Null with "false" in the correct version of the code (see accepted answer) but still doesn't work. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

in using $exists:true any type of index usage goes out of equation. You can modify the query as 
files = collection.find({"Data":{$ne:null}, Text:null})

Comment: `$ne: null` is not any easier to be backed by index than `$exists: true/false`, it seems. (in fact, it used to _not_ use index until a few versions ago). Do you have sources to back this claim?

Comment: I dont have any sources  ,but in general  when I run the query in prod $exists runs slower than e:{$nin:[null,""]} when e is indexed . Secondly null values are not indexed hence all the values present in index make the cut.

Comment: "Secondly null values are not indexed" - they are, [even in a sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

Comment: Tested on my machine and, indeed, `$exists` query uses the corresponding index.

Comment: Please check :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176310/  , Please can you confirm your claim

Comment: I trust mongo's explain plan over 7 year old answer. And so should you.